# PIG - HBASE - HBaseStorage key filter (gt, lt)

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

In a PIG script, I'm using HBaseStorage to load all the rows from an HBase-table.  However, I'd like to filter the rows by the rowkey.

I looked at the source code, and i can send in -gt & -lt through the constructor.  However, I can't figure out how to pass my value into the constructor.  It is a byte[]...

Here is where I'm at:

```
LOAD 'hbase://TABLE' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('CF:I','-caster HBaseBinaryConverter') AS (product_id:bytearray);
```

If possible could you pls provide sample code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "\x" with the hex digits to express the binary value. Check the source codes [here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pig/pig/0.11.1/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.java#384). For example,

```
LOAD 'hbase://TABLE' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('CF:I','-caster HBaseBinaryConverter -lt=\\x01\\x02\\xD4') AS (product_id:bytearray);
```

Comment: So the format is as follows: 300 -> \\x00\\x00\x01\x2C.  And for some reason the 'C' has to be capital letter else weirdness....